# How to cite a source when the source URL is suspicious

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks, external-links

The site whyandroid appears to have been a legitimate site at one point but is now redirecting in a very suspicious way. (After multiple redirects it either asks you to install an addon to your browser or asks to run flash.)

I saw this in a suggested edit removing the link. There are only about 10 posts on the site using the URL so I've already removed a few and flagged a couple of link only answers.

However in [android, webview, javascript injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734046/android-webview-javascript-injection)
the OP mentions the URL because that's where the code came from. If I simply remove the text it's no longer citing it's source but I'm concerned that naming the site in any way, even if the link is gone, could encourage users to try to find a site that may harm their machine.

In this case, is it better to remove the citation entirely or is it better to still cite it, sans link, with an explanation?

Comment: You may source with archive.org.

Answer (score 8):

Sourcing with an archival site is preferable in cases where the original source URL is not suitable for inclusion in the work. You may then cite the archived URL as you would any other Internet source.

## Options for referencing an archived source

To archive a URL, you need an exact snapshot of the website in question. One such service, [The Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) from Archive.org is great for resurrecting dead pages, but the URLs it generates are long and unwieldy, perhaps not suitable for your purposes.

Searche engine caching services, such as [Google Cache](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en) and similar can also be useful if the Wayback Machine hasn't indexed a page, but these are ephemeral and thus not well-suited to reference work.

Another service, [archive.is](http://archive.is/), can be used to create an archived snapshot of a webpage as it currently appears. Moreover, it generates unique short links for each snapshot, handy for inclusion  whenever space is limited. The site also provides ready-to-use citation entries for APA, MLA, etc.

---

## Combining other services with archive.is

In some cases, such as with the WhyAndroid URL (an infinite redirect), it may be advisable to combine the past views of the page (e.g., from Wayback Machine or Google Cache) with the snapshot functionality of archive.is. To do so, locate a snapshot of the original page, and then send that URL to archive.is:

### Example: WhyAndroid article

Here's what that process might look like for the WhyAndroid article:

1. Search for the URL in a cacing service like the Wayback Machine
2. Locate the cached URL. In this case, `https://web.archive.org/web/20101202065632/http://whyandroid.com/android/206-using-webviews.html`
3. Paste the URL into archive.is
4. Wait for the snapshot to be indexed. This may take some time.
5. Once the indexing is complete, you can copy the short URL for use anywhere. This snapshot's short link is `http://archive.is/w7Edy`

---

### Important things to consider

In this case, the Wayback Machine did not save the images along with the article. To work around this, I've found [a PDF copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20101202141952/http://whyandroid.com/android/206-using-webviews.pdf) (you may wish to shorten the link with bit.ly or similar, though).

Sidenote: WhyAndroid in fact links to a [more original source](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html) at the end of their article. Instead of referencing second-hand sources, I would suggest that in the future that you should *begin by tracing sources back as far as you can* to find a source that is more directly associated with the topic of discussion.

Here's a screenshot of where WhyAndroid linked to the source: [image]

Comment: *WhyAndroid in fact links to a more original source at the end of their article.* I was about to leave a comment to Coeur about that. The source code isn't even actually on that blog page either, it just links to it.

Comment: Do you agree with Blastfurnace that the link should just be removed when an archived version cannot be found? I think that was actually specific to that question but I'd like to get some opinions on the general case: code and/or text is cited as being from a 3rd party location, URL is now malicious, can't find an archived version of the page.

Comment: I'd avoid link shorteners. They obfuscate where an untrusted person is sending you... the length is irrelevant in a Stack Exchange post; as you've demonstrated some words are always better than the bare link.

Comment: @BSMP yes, dead links and images with no obvious archived version should be removed from a post. If the owner of the post is still maintaining it, they will notice the edit and eventually do something about it, otherwise the dead link will rest in peace.

Comment: @BSMP I'm a bit confused regarding your "_I was about to leave a comment to Coeur about that._", as my only prior participation to this discussion was a general "_You may source with archive.org._"

Comment: @Cœur - Oh, I'd written a comment like, "I took your advice and it turns out the legit version of the site was yanking content from other sites anyway." but got distracted before posting it. Not something I expected you to take action on or anything. Probably would have been better to just say, "Yep, just saw that all the pages on that site are like that." Sorry for the confusion.